# How to send a message to SLACK by chat.postMessage method

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, post, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send a message to Slack by using chat.postMessage. I can't understand whats wrong. I use GAS web application. Help me please to correct my code and explain what i've done wrong.

```js
function test_bot(vLookupResult_airport, vLookupResult_city_country, vLookupResult_resposibility, vLookupResult_version_v3, search_key, channel_id) {
  var payload = {
    "channel": channel_id,
    "text": {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "test text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  var option = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + "xoxb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", option);
```

Comment: I find a way. I should invite a Bot to my channel. Thats all.

Comment: have you set up the bot? what's the error message? we need more context here